# As an Indian transiting in Jordan, do I need to have a transit visa?

Tags: transit-visas, jordan

I'm an Indian passport holder, travelling to Tel Aviv, Israel (for which I have a visa) and transiting at Jordan. The transit time is less than 12 hours, if that's important. Do I need to worry about a transit visa? If so, can I get it on arrival? The transit is at Queen Alia airport at Amman and involves a change of flights, but I'm not sure of terminals.

Answer (score 1):

According [to the Emirates visa checker](http://www.emirates.com/english/plan_book/essential_information/visa_passport_information/find_visa_requirements/visa_passport_information_results.aspx?NC=IN&NV=India&DC=IL&DV=Israel&TC=JO&TV=Jordan&h=b2469c3e9c26c67ec08b744d7da0b8adc661dd1f) (which I beleive connects to TIMTAC?)

> ## Transit - Jordan (JO)
>
> #### Visa
>
> Visa required.
>
> #### TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
>
> Holders of onward tickets for a max. transit time of 48 hours.
>
> #### Additional Information:
>
> Passengers transiting Amman (AMM) to Aqaba (AQJ) must complete their entry formalities upon arrival at AMM.

So it looks like you will not need a visa. I would check that you don't require to leave the international zone of the airport however, as that will make things simpler for you. Also, there have been reports on this site of airport staff in India being reluctant to board Indian citizens, even when they do not need a visa if they cannot provide one. It may be worth gathering evidence of what you need (or not) to present at the desk.